# How to display the data from JSON in tableviewcell

Tags: ios

I need to list the data in the tableview.

```
{"data":[{"id":33,"question":"sqws","options":["option ,A","option ,A"],"button_type":"2","option_count":"2"}]}
```

This is my api pattern .

My code as follow:-

```
Model:-


class Model: NSObject {

        var question:String?
        var options:[String]?

        init?(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

            guard
                let question = dictionary["question"] as? String

                else {
                    return

            }

            if let options = dictionary["options"] as? [String]{
                print(options)

                self.options = options

            }


            self.question = question
             }

    }
```

datasourceModel:-

```
class DataSourceModel: NSObject {

    var dataListArray:Array<Model>? = []

    init(array :Array<[String:Any]>?) {
        super.init()
        var newArray:Array<[String:Any]> = []
        if array == nil{

            // newArray = self.getJsonDataStored22()
        }
        else{
            newArray = array!

        }

        var datalist:Array<Model> = []
        for dict in newArray{

            let model = Model(dictionary: dict)

            datalist.append(model!)
        }
        self.dataListArray = datalist
    }

}
```

viewmodel:-

```
class ViewModel: NSObject {

    var datasourceModel:DataSourceModel


    var filteredListArray:Array<DataSourceModel>? = []


    init(withdatasource  newDatasourceModel:DataSourceModel) {
        datasourceModel = newDatasourceModel
        print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)
    }

    func numberOfSections(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        print((datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!)
        return (datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!
    }

    func titleForHeaderInSection(atsection section: Int) -> ListModel {
        return datasourceModel.dataListArray![section]
    }



    func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {


        return (datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!
    }

    func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> Model{

    //print(datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.row])

    return  datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.row]

    }





    func loadData(completion :@escaping (_ isSucess:Bool) -> ()){


        loadFromWebserviceData { (newDataSourceModel) in

            if(newDataSourceModel != nil)
            {

                self.datasourceModel = newDataSourceModel!
                completion(true)

            }
            else{
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }

    func loadFromWebserviceData(completion :@escaping (DataSourceModel?) -> ()){


        Alamofire.request("http://www.example.com").validate(statusCode: 200..<300).validate(contentType: ["application/json"]).responseJSON{ response in


            print(response)

            switch response.result{


            case .success(let data):
                print("success",data)


                let result = response.result

                print(result)






                if     let wholedata = result.value as? [String:Any]{

                    print(wholedata)



                    if  let data = wholedata["data"] as? Array<[String:Any]>{

                        print(data)
                        print(response)




                        let newDataSource:DataSourceModel = DataSourceModel(array: data)

                        completion(newDataSource)


                    }
                }


            case .failure(let encodingError ):
                print(encodingError)

                //  if response.response?.statusCode == 404{

                print(encodingError.localizedDescription)

                completion(nil)

            }

        }}




}
```

viewcontroller:-

```
class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{


    private var reviewViewModel :ViewModel!


     var nameArray = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?, withViewModel viewModel:ViewModel) {

        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

        reviewViewModel  = viewModel
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {



        super.viewDidLoad()

        nameArray = ["Home","Message","Map","Setting"]





        reviewViewModel.loadData { (isSuccess) in


            if(isSuccess == true)
            {

                self.tableview.reloadData()

            }
            else{


                self.viewDidLoad()

            }

            //   self.viewDidLoad()

        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return (reviewViewModel.datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {





        let identifier = "HeaderCell"

        var headercell: =questionheader! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? = questionheader

        if headercell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "questionheader", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            headercell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? questionheader
        }

        headercell.setReviewData(reviews:reviewViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection:section))



      headercell.setReviewData(reviews:reviewViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: section))

        return headercell
    }



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // 2
        //return 1

        return reviewViewModel.numberOfRowsInSection(section: section)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let identifier = "Cell"
        var cell: NH_QuestionListCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? NH_QuestionListCell

        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "QuestionListCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? QuestionListCell
        }

       cell.setReviewData(reviews:reviewViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))


      return cell
    }




}
```

questionheader:-

```
 class questionheader: UITableViewCell {


        @IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // Initialization code
        }
        func setReviewData(reviews:QuestionListModel)

        {
            self.lblName.text = reviews.question
            print(self.lblName.text)

        }


        override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

            // Configure the view for the selected state
        }

    }
```

QuestionListCell:-

```
class QuestionListCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var question: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    func setReviewData(reviews:QuestionListModel)

    {

        print(reviews.options)
        print(reviews.options?[0])

        self.question.text = reviews.options?[0]
        print(self.question.text)

    }


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

So,here i got questions at sections .But according to my api i need to list the data contain in key option.

```
{"data":[{"id":33,"question":"sqws","options":["option ,A","option ,B"],"button_type":"2","option_count":"2"}]}
```

According to this i got the question in section and i need to display the options in tableviewcell That means option ,A and  option ,B should display in the tableviewcell.How to do?

Just like this[Just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUY8h.png)

Comment: how to solve the problem

Comment: add screenshot of the results you are seeing by executing the code.

Comment: @BhavinKansagara i have added the screen shot .please check.

Comment: better forward the link of your project on github @nahlaabdulnawal

Comment: Why classes inherited from `NSObject`? This is not Objective-C. And why sooo many optionals which are forced unwrapped anyway in many cases? And **NEVER EVER** call delegate methods containing `will`, `did` and `should` yourself.

Comment: how to display the options in tableviewcell

Comment: use the codable protocol to get json, if you are using swift4

Answer (score 0):

First thing is:

You should return the option count in this method

```
 func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {

    let objectAtSection: [String: String] = datasourceModel.dataListArray?[section]
    return Int(objectAtSection["option_count"])!
}
```

second, for showing the options in cell, update this method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = "Cell"
    var cell: NH_QuestionListCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? NH_QuestionListCell

    if cell == nil {
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "QuestionListCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? QuestionListCell
    }

   let objectAtSection: [String: String] = datasourceModel.dataListArray?[section]
   let optionsAtRow: [String] = objectAtSection["options"]
   cell.question.text = optionsAtRow[indexPath.row]
   return cell
}
```

Try and share the results

Comment: i need to do in mvvm way.So how to implement in that way

Comment: still i not got the output

Comment: update your question with the results you are seeing after edits